# Why the variable defined in the for loop is going above the upper limit when I want to print the output?

Tags: c#, linq, indexing

```cs
string table = "?-?";
string[] chars = { "&", "x" };
IEnumerable<string> vs = new List<string> { "" };

for (int i = 0; i < table.Length; i++)
{
    if (table[i] != '?')
        vs = vs.Select(x => x + table[i]);
    else
        vs = vs.SelectMany(x => chars.Select(y => x + y));
}
```

I can run and compile the above without any exceptions, but when I try to see the elements in `vs`, with `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", vs));`, I get a `System.IndexOutOfRangeException` in the line `vs = vs.Select(x => x + table[i]);`.

The cause of the exception is `i`.
The strange thing is that `i` is **3**, in the "Locals" window, but I have `i < table.Length` in the for loop. So `i` cannot be 3 but it is!

My question is why `i` becomes 3 and why the exception only appears when I want to print the output.

[image]

I've tried the following to print the output too, but I got the same result.

```cs
foreach (var comb in vs)
    Console.WriteLine(comb);
```

Comment: Nope this code definitely not throwing that exception .. just tried the same and can't reproduce

Comment: @Rahul did you add `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", vs));` at the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into the "Locals" window: your `i` variable gets the value of `3` - thus the exception.

And why is it 3? This is because you incremented it in the loop. But wait, your `Select` is inside of the loop, so it shouldn't be greater than 2, right?

Wrong.

This is called "a variable captured by a lambda". Search for this to read more.

The solution:

```
for (int i = 0; i < table.Length; i++)
{
    int j = i;
    vs = vs.Select(x => x + table[j]);
    // and so on
}
```

Comment: why I didn't get an exception before adding `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", vs));`?

Comment: @ParsaFat'hollahi because without this, you don't enumerate over `vs` and thus do not execute the linq queries at all. Your `Select` queries just won't be executed. Read about linq's deferred execution.

Answer (score -1):

Well, you need to call `ToList()` on the Linq query. Make changes like

```
public static void Main()
{
   string table = "?-?";
   string[] chars = { "&", "x" };
   List<string> vs = new List<string> { "" };

    for (int i = 0; i < table.Length; i++)
    {
        if (table[i] != '?')
            vs = vs.Select(x => x + table[i]).ToList();
        else
            vs = vs.SelectMany(x => chars.Select(y => x + y)).ToList();
    }
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", vs));
}
```

Output:

> &-&, &-x, x-&, x-x

Comment: No need to instantiate a bunch of lists because of a captured variable... Your solution is not effective and is a workaround. The OP doesn't **need** to call `ToList()` each time.

Comment: @ParsaFat'hollahi This helps because `ToList()` executes the deferred linq query (`Select()`) immediately - on each loop iteration. Without `ToList()`, this linq query will be executed only when you do `string.Join()` - this is called "deferred execution". The deferred execution uses the captured variable `i` which will have the value of 3 at execution time. Summarizing: you *could* use `ToList()`, but it's not effective - you instantiate unneeded objects (lists) just to work-around an overseen captured variable issue. Better fix the original problem.